# List file size in terminal

Tags: command-line, files

I want to list all files that has the text `VIPCustomer="true"` in it. I also want to just show file names that has `NewCustomer` in it. I do this with this:

```
grep -lr --include='*' 'VIPCustomer="true"' | grep NewCustomer
```

But how can I also include the file size of the files that are being listed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run `du` or `ls -s` on the filenames. You can use `xargs` to convert the output from `grep` to arguments for `du` or `ls`. Example:

```
grep -Zlr --include='*NewCustomer*' 'VIPCustomer="true"' | xargs -0 du --
grep -Zlr --include='*NewCustomer*' 'VIPCustomer="true"' | xargs -0 ls -s --
```

The `-Z`/`-0` options use ASCII nul-terminated input/output, so all valid filenames are safely handled.

Comment: xargs -0 ls -l at the end worked ! Thanks for the help!